# No such file or directory even if it exists - no read permission

Tags: linux, file-permissions, smb

I'm at a bit of a loss here and any help is appreciated.

I have a file on a mounted SMB drive that I cannot do anything with.

```
$ls -laFZd <file>
-rwxr-xr-x 1 <uid> <gid> ? 13300 Dec 13 05:52 <file>*
```

uid and gid are correct. Any command will return saying `No such file or directory` like

```
$ cat <file>
cat: <file>: No such file or directory
```

Same with `rm`, `mv`

`lsattr` gives error that it cannot open file for read.

I can see that, running `file` gives a clue:

```
$ file <file>
<file>: writable, executable, regular file, no read permission
```

even if everything looks correct with `getfacl`:

```
getfacl <file>
# file: <file>
# owner: <uid>
# group: <gid>
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Also note that other files in the same folder don't have any issues. All files are created by the same process around the same time.

Anyone with an idea would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The SMB share is from a cloud provider (CTERA) so I have limited information on the setup from their end. They are also looking into it.

They have a portal where we were able to delete the file but not read it. The file in question is an xsls.

The process is that we have a batch job running every night that creates file to this share then another process copying the file to another share and another directory on the same share. When all is done, it deletes the file. The copy to the same share goes through but not the copy to the other share and the original file is stuck in the no read permission state.

Comment: Is it possibly a junction point?  NTFS supports a couple of concepts that don't translate well to Linux.

Comment: I don't think so as other files in the same folder don't have any issues

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsattr <file>`? Also you could compare with other files in the same directory & check if it has `append only (a)` attribute?

Comment: `lsattr: No such file or directory While reading flags on <file>` and other files have the exact same attribute (except for the output of the `file` command)

Comment: What do you get when you give the absolute path with `lsattr`? Still same output? Also you could check `dmesg` or `/var/log` to find any filesystem/volume related errors

Comment: Same error with full path `lsattr`. 
I don't have root access to the server but I have asked to get this checked by the person responsible for the server.

Comment: What does it look like from the Windows side?  Can you `dir` that directory?  Do the permissions look right?

Comment: It is a service provided by CTERA so I don't know much form that end. There is a portal where we were able to delete the file (but could not open it). We did get the same new error on another file today (24h later).